# How to pass key/value in Helm via --set

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'd like to setup a [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) using the flag `--set` for the value `controller.service.labels`: any hint how to pass a multiple key/value argument to reach the desired result?

```
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  labels: 
    foo: bar   <<< my controller.service.labels passed via --set
    bizz: buzz <<<
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.24.3
    component: controller
    heritage: Tiller
    release: ingress-controller
  name: ingress-controller-nginx-ingress-controller
spec: 
  clusterIP: ""
  ports: 
    - 
      name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - 
      name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector: 
    app: nginx-ingress
    component: controller
    release: ingress-controller
  type: NodePort
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :)

```
--set controller.service.labels.foo="bar" \
--set controller.service.labels.bizz="buzz"
```

Easy peasy!